# How to check if jQuery UI widget is loaded?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I know I can check if jQuery UI core is loaded with `jQuery.ui`, but how to check if a widget (`draggable`) is loaded, I am using `typeof($('something').draggable) == 'function'`, is any better way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
if (typeof(jQuery.ui.draggable) != 'undefined'){
    // UI draggable is loaded
}
```

Comment: This doesn't actually seem to work for me even though the above answer seems to be in line with the jQuery documentation? `$.ui` doesn't seem to have any of the functions I create with widget yet `$()` does.

Comment: Was stepping through the code and found `constructor = $[ namespace ][ name ] = function( options, element ) { ... ` called when you define a widget...